# how to concatenate string variables into a third?

Tags: shell, string, variable

I need to concatenate two strings in bash, so that:

```
string1=hello
string2=world

mystring=string1+string2
```

`echo mystring` should produce

> helloworld

Comment: Terminal command `join` could also do the thing for you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

simply concatenate the variables:

```
mystring="$string1$string2"
```

Answer (score 59):

You don't need to use {} unless you're going to use bash variable parameters or immediate append a character that would be valid as part of the identifier. You also don't need to use double quotes unless you parameters will include special characters.

```
x=foo
y=bar
z=$x$y        # $z is now "foobar"
z="$x$y"      # $z is still "foobar"
z="$xand$y"   # does not work
z="${x}and$y" # does work, "fooandbar"
z="$x and $y" # does work, "foo and bar"
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for [z="$xand$y"   # does not work    .....    


z="${x}and$y" # does work, "fooandbar"]. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

In case you need to concatenate variables with literal strings:

```
string1=hello
string2=world
mystring="some ${string1} arbitrary ${string2} text"
```

`echo $mystring` will produce:

> some hello arbitrary world text

Comment: You can use the `${var}` format any time you like, but you only **need** it when `$var` is to be immediately followed by another valid variable-name character... eg: `$vararbitary` will interpret a variable named "vararbitary", but you can get around it by using `${var}arbitary` .... oops, I just saw khamer's abswer.. but I may as well leave the comment here.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to concatenate a lot of variables you can also use `+=` to append strings.. This may increase readability..

```
mystring=${string1}
mystring+=${string2}
mystring+=${string3}
mystring+=${string4}
echo ${mystring}
```

As mentioned by other answers the {} are not needed here but I personally always use them to avoid some syntax errors.

`+=` can also be used to append values to arrays: `array+=($b)`.