# How to show help for some bash command in less (like man do) rather than print it to console

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias, man

For example, there is no manual pages for `trap` command. Running:

```
man trap
```

will give:

```
No manual entry for trap
```

Running:

```
trap --help
```

will print help straight to bash console without using `less` like `man` do. And it is not handy to clog up console output. It is more user friendly to redirect help information to `less`:

```
trap --help | less
```

But it is not handy to print such quite long command each time to get help. How to configure it more shortly (something as alias) - for example, to use it like `help2 trap` (`help2` because probably it is not right to override existing `help` command behavior) or better more shortly just `hp trap` (hp is short meaning for help word)?

Comment: `trap` has a man page, just `man bash` since it's a built-in (which you can know via `type trap`).

Comment: Is there a way to jump directly to description of specific command, for example `trap` in `man bash`? I found it with `less` search by `trap` keyword but this takes time.

Comment: It's not less typing, but this works for me.

`man -P "less '+/^ *trap'" bash-builtins`

You might turn this into a shell function, parameterized in the page name and search string.

Comment: @TheNotoriousGBR This is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add the following function to `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Show help for command in less like man. Usage: hp cmd. For example:
# hp trap
hp() { "$@" --help | less; }
```

Source it to make visible in the opened bash console (or just reopen console):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Usage:

```
hp some_shell_command
```

Example of usage:

```
hp trap
```

---

Update

`hp() { "$1" --help | less; }`
replaced to
`hp() { "$@" --help | less; }`
to support commands with script parameter like `python test.py --help`

I checked the following cases (with Python 3.8.10):

- `hp python # executed as: python --help | less`
- `hp python test.py # executed as: python test.py --help | less`
- `hp python "te st.py" # executed as: python "te st.py" --help | less`
- `hp ./test # executed as: ./test.py --help | less`
- `hp "./te st" # executed as: "./te st.py" --help | less`

All this cases are working.
Thanks to [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) and [Chris Davies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/chris-davies) for theirs great advices!

Used test.py and "te st.py" with the following same content:

```
#!/bin/python

# Python code here taken from the following answer on the question:
# How do I access command line arguments? [duplicate]
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/42929351/1455694
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("simple_example")
parser.add_argument("counter", help="An integer will be increased by 1 and printed.", type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.counter + 1)
```

Output for `hp python "te st.py"`:

```
usage: simple_example [-h] counter

positional arguments:
  counter     An integer will be increased by 1 and printed.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

---

Related questions about `help`,  `man`, `info` commands:

- [Difference between help, info and man command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19451/difference-between-help-info-and-man-command)
- [Why do some commands have man pages and other commands use --help?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/why-do-some-commands-have-man-pages-and-other-commands-use-help)
- [command --help vs man command [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86571/command-help-vs-man-command)

---

This solution made with the help of the questions:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)
- [how to concatenate string variables into a third?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10263/how-to-concatenate-string-variables-into-a-third)

Comment: the proper way to do that would be something like `hp() { "$1" --help | less; }`, which would work even if the command was something like `./test release/foo`. (Of course a command like that would be awkward to use and would need to be quoted, so it's likely not often an issue, but in this case it's not too hard to write the function properly, and it's the same issue that could come up with arbitrary filenames.)

Comment: If you want to avoid security risks then don't use `eval`, and don't use unquoted variables

Comment: @ilkkachu I tested `hp() { "$1" --help | less; }` function with `hp "python test.py"` command. It gave "python test.py: command not found" error. Removing quotation marks from $1 has helped. With `hp() { $1 --help | less; }` the following cases are working: `hp pwd`, `hp ./test.py`, `hp "python test.py"`. I updated the answer.

Comment: @ChrisDavies probably in this particular case security risks will not appear. I had to remove quotation marks in order to fix case with spaces: `hp "python test.py"`. How do you think `hp() { $1 --help | less; }` is appropriate solution?

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for your one-liner. It is more nice. I added it to the answer.

Comment: AntonSamokat I've fixed your code again; you were right when using @ilkkachu's code but not when you removed the double quotes

Comment: You wrote, "_It gave "python test.py: command not found" error._"  - do you have a file called `python test py` (a single file that has a space in its name)? If not, the error message is correct

Comment: @AntonSamokat, ok, right, I saw the code using just `$1` and made the wrong assumption that passing other arguments wasn't required. If we want to allow that, then it would be `hp() { "$@" --help | less; }`, which would properly work with e.g. `hp python3 "./test version/foo.py"`.

Comment: In general, the point is that when the command line is first processed, the shell parses quotes and such and turns the command line into a list of distinct strings ("words") and _there's no need to process them any further_. Just use the list as-is. Doing that allows acting on arbitrary strings the normal way, with the user just having to quote them using the normal shell syntax, just like they would if they called `ls` on some file with an odd name. Expanding variables outside quotes invokes word-spltting, and just _breaks_ strings with whitespace (or glob chars), with no way to fix it.

Comment: Gentlemen, I absolutely love your great comments. I put "$@" to the function in answer and added `Update` section with use cases and test results. Thanks for the tips!